# Symfony 4 form validation returning "This value should not be blank." while trying to update User entity

Tags: php, symfony

I have a problem while trying to update User entity in Symfony 4.

I've created a `UserAccountLoginType` form where user can change their `e-mail` and `username` but when I'm trying to submit this form with new username/e-mail nothing happens. I'm sure that these two fields are correct and unique. After var_dumping `$form->getErrors()` I always get error:

> This value should not be blank.

There's no information which field causes this error.

*App\Entity\User.php:*

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Id\AbstractIdGenerator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="Email already taken")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="username", message="Username already taken")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
     * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="App\Utils\CustomGenerator")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=2, nullable=true)
     */
    private $language;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(max=4096)
     */
    private $plainPassword;

    /**
     * The below length depends on the "algorithm" you use for encoding
     * the password, but this works well with bcrypt.
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Assert\DateTime()
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\UserProfile", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $profile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="simple_array", nullable=true)
     */
    private $roles;
```

*App\Form\UserAccountLoginType.php:*

```
class UserAccountLoginType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username', TextType::class)
            ->add('email', TextType::class)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Zapisz'))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

*App\Controller\UserController.php:*

```
/**
 * @Route("/system/user/account/login", name="user_account_login_mail")
 */
public function accountLoginMail(Request $request) {

    $user = $this->getUser();

    if (!$user) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'Nie znaleziono użytkownika.'
        );
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(UserAccountLoginType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();

            $this->addFlash(
                'info',
                'Zapisano ustawienia!'
            );

            return $this->redirectToRoute('user_account_login_mail');
        }

        $em->refresh($user);
    }

    return $this->render('user/account_login_mail.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'user' => $user
    ));
}
```

Does anybody know how to fix this issue?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have setters and getters defined in the entity class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved! I've opened a Profiler and now I can see source of this issue.

```
Caused by:
    ConstraintViolation {#4406 ▼
        root: Form {#2794 …}
        path: "data.plainPassword"
        value: null
}
```

The thing is that I haven't append the `plainPassword` field which is required to make changes on User entity.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the following in your twig file :

{{form_errors(formulario)}}

or doing var_dump(formulario->getErrors(true)); with parameter true inside.

Here you would obtain the error.

Comment: Thanks. There were too many parameters to display them using `var_dump` or `form_errors`. But Profiler was very helpful :)